# How can I increase my peak current in this switching circuit?

Tags: capacitor, current

I have a high side switch configuration that is switching at 2 kHz. The switch is on at 60 us and off for 440 us. As you can see in my schematic the supply 12V-T is from a 7812. The load is a big inductor with a resistance of 0.4 Ω and the FET I'm using has an RDSon of 1.5 Ω.

[image]

During the on period I have calculated that the peak current is 12 V / (1.5 Ω + 0.4 Ω) which is approx. 6.3 A. Powering from a benchtop supply, the average current is approx. 800 mA. As the max current that is supplied by the 7812 is 2.2 A it is resulting in severe voltage droop as seen in the image. On the left side of the image you can see the initial 12 V start but over 60 us it droops to approx. 5 V.

[image]

I attempted to negate this by adding more capacitors in parallel with C46 up to 9900 uF but this has no measurable effect. What can I do to improve my peak current to deal with the inrush? Some droop is acceptable but the 7 V at the moment seems excessive. It's not affecting performance of the system but I'm worried that the system may fail sooner as it seems to be operating out of spec. i.e. pulling the voltage down.

Comment: I've got some info about what you wanted to share, but I really want to know more about what you want to achieve with the coil. Could you set aside all the trees you are looking at right now and talk about the forest for a moment, so to speak? What's your goal?

Comment: The "pulling down" is the natural back-lash from the inductor and could easily destroy your MOSFET if it hasn't done so already.

Comment: @Andy aka could you please elaborate as i'm not understanding? The FET is avalanche rated...

Comment: Google back-emf in inductor circuits.

Comment: @Andy aka this is part of a system that measures the generated back emf. Something like a freewheeling diode ( I think you're suggesting that the design needs one) can't be used in this system.

Comment: You should choose an FET with a lower RDSon. But beware 12V across 0.4 ohm is 30A.

Comment: While I *don't* see 12 V supplied through a 7812, that should limit current to about 2.2 A as mentioned: the bypass capacitor would need to supply a substantial part of the charge for the voltage not to droop anywhere near 6 A. 60 μs*6.3 A is about 0.4 mC, with 3.3 mF the voltage swing should be about 0.12 V+ESR*6 A?! Something is off: Can you *scope* the current? For a 10% current ripple, peak current would be about 0.85 A *assuming linear change*.

Comment: @RussellH there aren't many N type MOSFETs with particularly low RSon that also have the avalanche ratings that are necessary to prevent the MOSFET from being destroyed by the back EMF generated by the load unfortunately.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe it's necessary to add high power resistors in series with the load to artifically limit the current to the max output of the 2.2A provided by the 7812

Comment: What is the inductor being used for? Maybe a different configuration could achieve the same goal.

Comment: Perhaps try a non-avalanche FET with low RDSon and a series diode with a suitably high voltage rating.  You’ll need something better than a 7812 to supply the additional current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increase peak current, you can

- Wait much longer than 60μs (but this might require a larger capacitor C46)
- Increase the potential difference above 12V
- Use a MOSFET with lower on-resistance

Here's why:

With inductors, there's no "inrush" current. On the contrary, inductors take time to start conducting, the very opposite behavior to capacitors. You can apply whatever sudden potential difference you like across an inductor, and initially it will offer no opposition, and pass no current. Thereafter, current rises in a kind of "upside-down exponential decay", eventually settling at some maximum.

On the left below is the situation where we have 12V trying to push current through a 1.9Ω resistance (the combination of MOSFET and coil resistances) and an inductor. In the middle is what happens if we increase that resistance, and on the right is if we somehow decrease it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTqL4C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The nature of inductance is to oppose change of current through it, and this gives rise to a slow growth of current when a potential difference is applied. This can be seen if I plot the graph of current vs. time for those three examples:

[image]

The formula for these curves is

$$ I = I_{MAX} \left( 1 - e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}} \right) $$

where \$\tau = \frac{L}{R}\$ is the time constant, related to how fast current rises (L being inductance and R the resistance through which it "charges"). There are only two variables you can change to reduce the time it takes to reach some current, and they are maximum (final) current \$I_{MAX}=\frac{12V}{R}\$ and resistance \$R\$.

From your oscilloscope curve, I estimated the inductance of your coil to be something of the order of 100μH, perhaps more. To obtain 6.3A through that coil requires energy:

$$ E = \frac{1}{2} L I^2 = \frac{1}{2} \times 100\mu H \times (6.3A)^2 = 2mJ $$

The maximum power that your 7812 can deliver, to to anything, is \$P = 2.2A \times 12V = 26W\$. Over a period of 60μs, that's a total energy of:

$$ E = P \times t = 26W \times 60\mu s = 1.5mJ $$

That's a little short. For this reason alone, there's no way you can get 6.3A through that inductor, in that time, from that voltage source.

The solution that you proposed, capacitance C46, seems like a good idea, at first sight. The energy stored in 3300μF, charged to 12V is:

$$ E = \frac{1}{2}CV^2 = \frac{1}{2} \times 3.3mF \times 12^2 = 240mJ $$

That's way more than the 2mJ you need to deliver to the coil. And there'll be hardly any drop in voltage across the capacitor due to it discharging a little. It sounds good.

Here's the real problem: with a 12V supply, and a resistance of 1.9Ω (coil and transistor resistance), you simply can't get 6.3A through 100μH of inductance in 60μs.

With a total resistance of 0.5Ω, and a potential difference of 12V, you *could* achieve 6.3A in 60μs. But *your* total resistance is 1.9Ω, and to get to 6A (even if your voltage source had no current limit) would take much, much longer. More like 1ms.

That leaves you with only one option; increase the maximum current, and to do that you must increase the potential difference. In your system, there is simply no way for that inductor to reach 6.3A in 60μs unless you increase the voltage above 12V.

Even with a capacitor, no matter how large, you still have the same constraint. If the resistance through which the inductor is "charging" is 1.9Ω, the rise of current through the inductor is simply too slow.

The drop in voltage across the inductor to 4V is not because your regulator isn't strong enough, or the capacitor isn't large enough, its because that's what happens to voltage across inductors, over time. You can apply any potential you like across an inductor, initially it will not oppose that. But as time progresses, it passes more and more current, until it eventually becomes a short circuit (or 0.4Ω in your case), at which point there's no voltage across it other than that due to its own resistance.

Take a look at the curve of voltage across the left-most inductor from the circuits above:

[image]

If the yellow trace on your oscilloscope is measuring voltage across the inductor, it's no surprise that it resembles this. That's what inductor voltages look like when you suddenly apply a fixed voltage across them, via a resistance.

Comment: Very interesting answer, I need some time to digest this. I wonder if it's a non-issue then. Could I just leave my circuit as is and not expect any issues from this? I was concerned that the circuit was too small a load and would limit the lifetime of the voltage regulator

Comment: Whatever energy is stored seems to get dissipated in about 10 μs - in a 820 Ω resistor?!

Comment: @greybeard It looks like it. The voltage across the 820Ω looks huge, can't see how far it falls on the trace. It must be far, big \$\frac{V^2}{R}\$ power, for all the energy to be gone in 10µs.

Comment: @greybeard also that oscillation looks like it might be the inductor ringing with the MOSFET source capacitance. I imagine some energy will take that capacitive route out.

Comment: @greybeard I forgot, when the MOSFET diode breaks down, that will be a very low impedance route. Lots of places for the energy to go.

Comment: @Simon Fitch the back EMF generated is -200V and the FET is rated for repetitive avalanche energy of 15mJ and single pulse avalanche energy of 700mJ. The FET is basically designed for this. Also, the ringing is mostly from the capacitance of the wire that connects the coil to the cable (5m coaxial). Just to clarify most of these things being pointed out are normal for the end use which is a metal detector.

Answer (score 0):

Your input switching frequency is far too low. Bump that circuit to 20 kHz and it will work much better.

Comment: At a higher frequency the peak current will be reduced